# iOS: Compare two NSDate-s without time portion

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I want to compare two dates: date1 and date2

```
2011-06-06 12:59:48.994 Project[419:707] firstDate:2011-06-06 10:59:21 +0000
2011-06-06 12:59:49.004 Project[419:707] selectedData:2011-06-06 10:59:17 +0000
```

but these dates have different time and when I use NSOrderedSame it don't work fine, how can I solve?

my code:

```
NSDate *firstDate = [[appDelegate.project objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:3];
NSDate *secondDate = [[appDelegate.project objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:4];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger comps = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);

NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps 
                                                            fromDate:firstDate];
NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps 
                                                            fromDate:secondDate];
NSDateComponents *date3Components = [calendar components:comps fromDate:appDelegate.selectedDate];

NSLog(@"firstDate:%@", [date1Components date]);
NSLog(@"secondDate:%@", [date2Components date]);
NSLog(@"selectedData:%@", [date3Components date]);

NSComparisonResult compareStart = [[date1Components date] compare: [date3Components date]]; 
NSComparisonResult compareEnd = [[date2Components date] compare: [date3Components date]]; 

if ((compareStart == NSOrderedAscending || compareStart == NSOrderedSame)
     && (compareEnd == NSOrderedDescending || compareEnd == NSOrderedSame))

{
    NSLog(@"inside");
```

Then I want to compare my dates and entry inside the "if" when  date1 <= selectedDate <= date2; now I understand because I have a warning: I should add this "[date1Components date]" and it work; the problem is that I have in the NSLog null values, why??

Comment: Instead of `NSLog(@"firstDate:%@", [date1Components date]);` try `NSLog(@"firstDate:%@", [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components]);` Any change?

Comment: now is 2011-06-05 22:00:00 +0000 why?????

Comment: probably some timezone/DST magic

Comment: it work all fine: i write [date1Components setTimeZone:[ NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:(+0*3600) ] ] ; and NSComparisonResult compareStart = [[calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components] compare: [calendar dateFromComponents:date3Components]]; thanks...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger comps = (NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear);

NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps 
                                                fromDate: date1];
NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps 
                                                fromDate: date2];

date1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
date2 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];

NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];
if (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
} else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
}  else {
    //the same
}
```

---

There is another handy method to create for a given date the date that represents the start of a given unit: [`[aCalendar rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html)
To illustrate how this method works, see this code, that easily creates the date for the beginning of the day, week, month and year for a given date (here: now).

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *startOfToday = nil;
NSDate *startOfThisWeek = nil;
NSDate *startOfThisMonth = nil;
NSDate *startOfThisYear = nil;
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfToday interval:NULL forDate:now];
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfThisWeek interval:NULL forDate:now];
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfThisMonth interval:NULL forDate:now];
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSYearCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfThisYear interval:NULL forDate:now];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:now]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:startOfToday]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:startOfThisWeek]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:startOfThisMonth]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:startOfThisYear]);
```

result:

```
Thursday, July 12, 2012, 4:36:07 PM Central European Summer Time 
Thursday, July 12, 2012, 12:00:00 AM Central European Summer Time 
Sunday, July 8, 2012, 12:00:00 AM Central European Summer Time 
Sunday, July 1, 2012, 12:00:00 AM Central European Summer Time 
Sunday, January 1, 2012, 12:00:00 AM Central European Standard Time
```

this allows us to shorten the first code to:

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&date1 interval:NULL forDate:date1];
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&date2 interval:NULL forDate:date2];

NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];
if (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
} else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
}  else {
    //the same
}
```

Note, that in this code, `date1` and `date2` will be overwritten. Alternatively you can pass in a reference to another NSDate pointer for `startDate` as shown in the code above, where `now` stays untouched.

Comment: I have a warning: "NSDateComponents may not respond to compare"

Comment: Does the first implementation overwrite date1 and date2, seems it will set hour, minute and seconds to 0 since:
date1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
date2 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];

Comment: @McGar yes, it assigns new objects to the variables.

Comment: As of 2016 at least, ``NSCalendar`` has a host of useful date comparison methods.

Comment: Still helpful in 2020 for me. I found `[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&startOfToday interval:NULL forDate:now];` useful in my app.

Answer (score 27):

I have used another method with NSDateFormatter and a string comparison, less smarter than 
NSDate *compare* method but faster to write and flexible enough to do variety of comparison :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

if ([[dateFormat stringFromDate:date1] isEqualToString:[dateFormat stringFromDate:date2]])
{
    //It's the same day
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Okay, so it's a few years after the original question was asked, but it's probably worth mentioning that [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscalendar) now has a number of methods that make certain date comparison questions much more straight-forward:

```
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
Bool sameDay = [currentCalendar isDate:dateA inSameDayAsDate:dateB];
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift Version** , Comparing Dates and ignoring their time.

```
let dateExam1:NSDate = NSDate.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 300)
let dateExam2:NSDate = NSDate.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10000)

let currCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

let dateCompanent1:NSDateComponents = currCalendar.components([.Year,.Month,.Day], fromDate: dateExam1)
let dateCompanent2:NSDateComponents = currCalendar.components([.Year,.Month,.Day], fromDate: dateExam2)

let date1WithoutTime:NSDate? = currCalendar .dateFromComponents(dateCompanent1)
let date2WithoutTime:NSDate? = currCalendar .dateFromComponents(dateCompanent2)
if (date1WithoutTime != nil) && (date2WithoutTime != nil)
{
    let dateCompResult:NSComparisonResult = date1WithoutTime!.compare(date2WithoutTime!)
    if (dateCompResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame)
    {
        print("Same Dates")
    }
    else
    {
        print("Different Dates")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating @LuAndre answer swift 5

```
    let dateExam1 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 300)
    let dateExam2 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10000)

    let currCalendar = Calendar.current

    let dateCompanent1 = currCalendar.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day], from: dateExam1)
    let dateCompanent2 = currCalendar.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day], from: dateExam2)


    if  let date1WithoutTime = currCalendar.date(from:dateCompanent1), let dateCompanent2 = currCalendar.date(from:dateCompanent2) {
            let dateCompResult = date1WithoutTime.compare(dateCompanent2)
            if (dateCompResult == ComparisonResult.orderedSame)
            {
                print("Same Dates")
            }
            else
            {
                print("Different Dates")
            }
        
    }
```