# iOS PHP like array, for storing multiple values systematically

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have some `NSDates` that are incremented and looped.

In the loop I need to check if the current date `isEqualToDate` in my array.

Each date key then needs to have multiple string values associated with it, something like this in PHP

```
$array['date'][0]['string']
$array['date'][1]['string']
etc
```

I have read a little, and I understand that Objective-C does not support these kinds of arrays, what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Mutable Dictionary to hold everything

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Adding values to your dictionary

```
[myDates setObject:myArrayOfStrings forKey:myDate];
```

Comparing dates without comparing the time (hours/minutes/seconds).
Credit where credit is due: [iOS: Compare two NSDate-s without time portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252622/ios-compare-two-nsdate-s-without-time-portion)

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; 
NSInteger comps = (NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit);

NSDateComponents *date1Components = [calendar components:comps 
                                            fromDate: date1];
NSDateComponents *date2Components = [calendar components:comps 
                                            fromDate: date2];

date1 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date1Components];
date2 = [calendar dateFromComponents:date2Components];

NSComparisonResult result = [date1 compare:date2];
if (result == NSOrderedAscending) {
} else if (result == NSOrderedDescending) {
}  else {
    //the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C this is like an `NSArray` into  `NSDictionary` with **date** key.
**example:-**

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"date":@[@"date-1", @"date-2"]};
```

**Output is:**

```
date = (
    "date-1",
    "date-2"
);
```

And you can fetch those dates like:

```
NSString *dateString = [[dict objectForKey:@"date"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

**OR**

```
// This is new syntax of dictionary and array
NSString *dateString = dict[@"date"][0];
```

It will give you date of `0` index.
This is about array type, Now See How to check **date** is present in **array** or not. If your date is `NSString` type then you can check simply

```
if ([[dic objectForKey:@"date"] containsObject:@"date-1"])
{
    // date-1 is present in array
}
```

If date is `NSDate` then

```
NSArray *dates = [dic objectForKey:@"date"];
for (id obj in dates)
{
    NSComparisonResult result = [currentDate compare:obj];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        // NSDate is present; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the fancy new syntax for dictionaries too.