# Finding the Date "IF Then Statement"

Tags: ios, date

I have an application for iPhone that gives information based on the current date. For example if the date is 10/28/13, it will say Today's weather is.... etc. How can I use an "If-Then" statement to find the current date? Or is there another better way of automatically finding the date and adjusting the display of the application?

I've tried implementing this by using a google calendar API but could't get that to work either.

Thanks a lot! This is my 2nd app ever on iOS so I need a lot of help! Thanks!

EDIT Just in case anyone needs this later on, this is what I got to finally work for me

```
     NSDateFormatter *df= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"2013-10-27"];
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:@"2013-10-28"];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&date1 interval:NULL forDate:date1];
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit startDate:&currentDate interval:NULL forDate:currentDate];
if ([currentDate isEqualToDate:date1]) {
    crowdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", itsOk];
} else {
    crowdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Not Working"];
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for what you've tried?

Comment: I tried implementing the TouchXML API, but kept getting a lot of errors so I gave up on that.

Comment: The point of SO is to get help working through errors.  If you need someone to write this code for you, then you should hire a programmer.

Comment: Something like `if (todayWanted) { currentDate = [NSDate date]; }`

Comment: You can't use `==` to see if two object have the same value. Use `isEqual:` or in this case use `isEqualToDate:`. Also, why do you needlessly `alloc/init` `dt1` and `dt2`?

Comment: Also, `currentDate` will never equal the others. `currentDate` includes the time down to the nearest millisecond.

Comment: This is bogus: `[[NSDate date] init]`

Comment: @RyanBurgess For future reference please do not make such big changes to your question. You posted your original code and people provided comments and answers based on that code. But you then replaced that code with your fixed code. Now the comments and answers appear worthless. In the future, if you wish to update your question with what worked, leave the rest of the question as it was and add your new info at the end. This makes it better for people seeing this question and the answers in the future. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSDate date]
```

will return the current date. You can then display the date in the format you prefer by configuring and using an instance of `NSDateFormatter`.

The [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) by Apple is a good reference.

---

Ok you have several mistakes in your code, let's go through them

```
NSDate *dt1 = [[NSDate alloc] init]; 
NSDate *dt2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

Considered that you are assigning this two variables immediately after their initialization, the `alloc`/`init` is useless, just do

```
NSDate *date1 = [df dateFromString:@"2013-10-27"]; 
NSDate *date2 = [df dateFromString:@"2013-10-28"];
```

Also

```
NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate date] init];
```

is wrong. `date` returns an already initialized object. Calling `init` on it is undefined behavior. Just do

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
```

Finally and most importantly you cannot compare dates doing

```
currentDate == dt1
```

`==` compares pointers, i.e. you are comparing object identity instead of object equality. If you want to check whether two `NSDate` objects represent the same date, use

```
[currentDate isEqualToDate:date1]
```

Note that this will compare the full date, time information included. If you want to check just the date portion, you can refer to this question: [iOS: Compare two NSDate-s without time portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252622/ios-compare-two-nsdate-s-without-time-portion)

Comment: Sorry, please check my original post. I updated it to show what happened now.

Comment: @RyanBurgess Ok I updated my answer to address the issues with your code

Comment: Thanks so much! Please check my OP again...I still am having problems getting it to work.

Comment: Ok the issue is simply that the two dates are not equal. The current date includes also the time information, whereas `date` doesn't. I'm gonna add a note about it.

Comment: So even though the date format is set to YY-MM-DD it still shows the hours and minutes and seconds? Which is why they won't equal?

Comment: Don't confuse `NSDate` and it's representation. `NSDate` is an object containing all the information about date/time/timezone, whereas `NSDateFormatter` only affects the way the date is displayed. If you create a date without providing the time information, the `NSDate` object will contain a default value for it, which I suppose is `00:00 UTC`

Comment: Thank you so much! After reading that page you sent me to I finally got it to work!