# Adding Days to NSDate malfunction

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

So I'm creating an app that tracks daily,weekly,monthly budget and stuck on this code. It works and it doesn't work and maybe I'm not even showing you the right portion of everything. There's times it works. Let say I start at 24 Hours remaining, and skip 1-2 days ahead, it will add the hours instead of subtract for some reason. And the other times it will work fine. (by fine I mean reset the next day and have 23 hours left if i'm checking an hour later the next day). Don't mind the start date, it doesn't matter.

```
NSString *start = @"06-08-2013 12:30:00";

int typeDays = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"typeKey"];
if (typeDays == 0) {
    days = 1;
} else if (typeDays == 1) {
    days = 7;
} else if (typeDays == 2) {
    days = 30;
}
NSLog(@"typedays:%i", typeDays);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setDay:days];
newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                   dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                   toDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"origDateKey"] options:0];



self.untilDeparture = [[SKEvent alloc] initWithStartDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:start]
                                              andEndDate:newDate];
```

This is where I get the hours/days:

```
  NSString *testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f", [self.untilDeparture.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]] / 3600];
testInt = [testString intValue];
NSLog(@"string:%@ and int:%i", testString, testInt);
if (testInt < 1 ) {
    NSLog(@"asdasdasd");
    [self resetAllData];
    [self viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self reloadLabel];

}

dateHours = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f Hours", [self.untilDeparture.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]] / 3600];
dateDays = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f Days Left", [self.untilDeparture.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]] / 3600 / 24];
if ([dateDays isEqualToString:@"1 Days Left"] || [dateDays isEqualToString:@"0 Days Left"]) {
    dateDays = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.0f Hours Left", [self.untilDeparture.endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]] / 3600];
}
self.daysLeftLabel.text = dateDays;
```

Then when I reset the data:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newDate forKey:@"origDateKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Is your initial date August 6th or June 8th?

Comment: the Start date doesn't matter at all. It sort of a place holder

Comment: I dont understand what you are asking and what your issue is. Your code you have will add x days to your `toDate` date object. One issue I do see that could happen is if you have your dateFormat set for the time as `HH` yet your time is actually 12 hour format instead of 24 hour. I had this issue awhile back.

Comment: Let me add a few more bits of code.

Comment: `[self viewWillAppear:YES];` you should never ever call that on your own.

Comment: `3600 / 24` due to daylight saving times days can be 23, 24 or 25 hours long. don't divide time interval like that.

Comment: see here to see how you can check if 2 dates are during the same day. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252622/ios-compare-two-nsdate-s-without-time-portion/6252686#6252686