# Comparing 2 dates, error in NSDateComponents

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate

I have 2 dates. Date1 in yyyy-MM-dd 21:00:00 +0000. Date2 in yyyy-MM-dd

I need to compare it and get age result.

Problem is that Ia have an error in NSDateComponents string.

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];

NSDate *date2temp = uBirthdate;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date2temp];
[dateString stringByAppendingString:@" 21:00:00 +0000"];
 NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date2 toDate:date1 options:0];
NSInteger editedAge = components.year;

NSLog(@"%d ", editedAge);
```

It will be better to cut off '21:00:00 +0000' from date1, but I do not know how can I do it

Comment: Date2 should be `nil`, since your added something to your dateString, but didn't change the format of the `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: @Larme, thanks, Do you know can I remove  '21:00:00 +0000' from date1? and get NSDate like yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: @user3358463: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252622/ios-compare-two-nsdate-s-without-time-portion/6252686#6252686

Comment: You are confused.  An NSDate object contains no timezone or date format information -- it's purely a number.  The format and timezone are established when you run it through NSDateFormatter.